# Sound mixers in Vista/7

Tags: c#, .net, naudio

How can I change values in windows sound mixers in Windows Vista/7? I'm using NAudio. If I'm using Windows XP, that is very simple, I'm using `NAudio.Mixer`. But if I try do this in Windows 7, i can't see all sound mixers. What i need to do?
P.S. This mixers values i need change.[image]

//
added.
This code:

```
        MMDeviceEnumerator enumerator = new MMDeviceEnumerator();
        var dev = enumerator.GetDefaultAudioEndpoint(DataFlow.Render, Role.Multimedia);
        var endpoint = dev.AudioEndpointVolume;
```

I see in endpoint only that:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

NAudio.Mixer is a wrapper for the now obsolete ACM Mixer APIs. With Windows Vista and above, the [Core Audio API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd370802%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is used instead. NAudio does contain a large amount of interop wrappers for these APIs, but not everything you might want to use has been wrapped an extra layer into an easy to use .NET object yet.  Start by getting hold of devices using `MMDeviceEnumerator`. This will let you get at the AudioEndpointVolume interface for each MMDevice, which may give you what you want.

Comment: And what i need to do with AudioEndpointVolume. You can see in my post, i add code and value.